# Quadratic forms and real quadratic fields

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, quadratic-forms

When we have a squarefree, negative integer $d$, class number of $\mathbb{Q}\sqrt{d}$ is equal to the number of positive definite reduced binary quadratic forms of discriminant $d$ or $4d$ depending on whether $d \equiv_{4} 2,3$ or $d \equiv_4 1$.

Do we have a such relation when we have a positive $d$ and real quadratic number field $\mathbb{Q}\sqrt{d}$? Can we say something like 'the class number of the number field is equal to the negative definite quadratic forms of fixed discriminant' ?

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_class_group#Properties), "For $d < 0$, the ideal class group of ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{d})$ is isomorphic to the class group of integral binary quadratic forms of discriminant equal to the discriminant of ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{d})$. For $ d > 0$, the ideal class group may be half the size since the class group of integral binary quadratic forms is isomorphic to the narrow class group of $Q(\sqrt{d})$." A textbook reference is also given